# ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services.drupal: 'postgres'

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, drupal

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3"

services:
    drupal:
        image: drupal
        ports:
        - "8080:80"
        volumes:
        - drupal-modules:/var/www/html/modules
        - drupal-profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
        - drupal-sites:/var/www/html/sites
        - drupal-themes:/var/www/html/themes
        postgres:
            image: postgres
            environment:
                - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypasswd

volumes:
    drupal-modules:
    drupal-profiles:
    drupal-sites:
    drupal-themes:
```

As I run

```
$ docker-compose up
```

I get:

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.drupal: 'postgres'
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation in your `docker-compose.yml` is not correct, since `.yml` files are indent-sensitive.

You have three errors:

1. `ports` is a `key:value` data, so `-` should be indented in the next line.
2. `volumes` is a `key:value` data, so `-` should be indented in the next line.
3. `postgres` service's indentation should be in the same level as `drupal`.

So your file should look like this to work:

```
version: "3"

services:
    drupal:
        image: drupal
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - drupal-modules:/var/www/html/modules
            - drupal-profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
            - drupal-sites:/var/www/html/sites
            - drupal-themes:/var/www/html/themes
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypasswd

volumes:
    drupal-modules:
    drupal-profiles:
    drupal-sites:
    drupal-themes:
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Every time you see

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for
```

it is likely the problem lies in wrong indent, as this is the case.

First, both `postgres` and `drupal` are containers (so `services`), and so they must have the same indent level, that is, one indentation level less than `services`.
Put one indentation level less to the whole `postgres` structure/tree.

Second, every element starting with `-` must have one indent level more than the element it belongs to.
So add one more indent level to the elements of `ports` and `volumes`.

Here is the docker-compose.yml corrected:

```
version: "3"

services:
    drupal:
        image: drupal
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - drupal-modules:/var/www/html/modules
            - drupal-profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
            - drupal-sites:/var/www/html/sites
            - drupal-themes:/var/www/html/themes
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypasswd

volumes:
    drupal-modules:
    drupal-profiles:
    drupal-sites:
    drupal-themes:
```